# Using *args and **kwargs instead of explicitly listing expected parameters

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

When working on a project where I have a lot of nested function calls and object hierarchies I was wondering what is the best practice to pass all required parameters to the highest layer and from there step-wise to the lower layers.

Example: 3 classes with their needed (constructor) parameters:

Class A: a, b

Class B: c, d, e

Class C: f

Class A holds an instance of B and B holds an instance of C. They are initialized in the constructor of the respective parent. So this means that the one who is using my code will only initialize a new object of A and have to pass all parameters a,b,c,d,e,f to A where they are processed or further distributed.

Example code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f):
        b = B(c, d, e, f)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, c, d, e, f):
        c = C(f)

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        pass
```

My first attempt was to list all parameters that a class and all their children needs directly in the constructor, but this is very prone to errors and also has a very high code redundancy, especially when it comes to providing default values at every layer. So I am thinking of using **kwargs and *args instead.

This would have the advantage that I could just pass those to the children and every layer could just take the arguments it needs from there.

However, the disadvantage would be that someone who wants to use a class of this hierarchy could not use the IDE's auto-completion to see which parameters are expected.

What is considered the best practice in Python 3 for this?

Comment: You may consider providing an illustrative code.

Comment: *"They are initialized in the constructor of the respective parent"* - I'd recommend reading about inversion of control, that's a bit of an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Kanak thanks for the hint. Added it

Comment: @jonrsharpe I also was thinking in using something like dependency injection, but that feels a bit too much for this project

Comment: Any reason you can't just let B just accept an instance of C and A accept an instance of B instead of one massive signature that tries to do everything?

Comment: You say that, but you're also here asking a question related to the pain you're feeling from *not* applying that principle! You don't have to go to a full DI framework, you can just invert the creation of those instances as @Jon suggests.

Comment: Yes, maybe it will be better to do it like @Jon proposed. Is this already some 'soft' kind of DI? For my understanding it is, but I am no expert.

Comment: According to https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html it is

Answer (score 1):

Coding shouldn't be a mean to satisfy any IDE requirements, you're talking about `not use the IDE's auto-completion to see which parameters are expected...` Your code shouldn't be written to make your IDE happy, instead it should be easy to be uses by other coders. What does this mean? Your exposed public interfaces should be intuitive and easy to learn by people, not IDEs. I'd say one of the many requisites that good code satisfies is whether you don't even need to read any doc at all but the public interface are self-explanatory.

Here's an interesting programming quote for you to consider:

> The ideal numbers of arguments for a function is zero (niladic). Next
>   comes one (monadic), followed closely by two (dyadic). Three arguments
>   (triadic) should be avoided where possible. More than three (polyadic)
>   requires very special justification ‐ and then shouldn't be used
>   anyway.

By looking at the non-relevant example you've proposed I can say straight-away that's not good OOP design, not just in terms of exposed public interfaces but also in terms of relationships (hierarchies should be created with proper reasoning). Maybe if you presented a real world-case I could advice further to make proper refactoring but with meaningless imaginary code with no use-cases and fictional meaningless parameters I don't see the point.

In any case, the best advice I can give you is about trying to come up with good encapsulated objects with proper logical relationships and thin self-explanatory public interfaces. Said otherwise, make your code "attractive" and "pleasant" to be used by others and you'll be fine :)

Comment: The original problem is a text preprocessing task. I use WikiCorpus from gensim to parse the english wikipedia dump. This class offers me a callback to change the tokenization (i.e. if to splits at sentences, words, etc.). Therefore I wrote my own tokenizer. Since this tokenizer further cleans the tokens, I also wrote a TextPreprocessor class that is used inside my tokenizer. So all in all I have a class that wraps WikiCorpus and instantiates the Tokenizer. This tokenizer instantiates the TextPreprocessor.
But after a bit of research I think using the DI approach is the best option

Comment: It would also allow me to change the tokenizer or TextPreprocessor without having to adapt any code in the respective "higher class" (that contains the element that I want to change).

Comment: Ok, that explantion is much better and now your problem makes a little bit more sense, next time I'd recommend you come up with something more real instead these fictional mcves so the answers you'll get will be of higher quality. Indeed, the tokenizer shouldn't instantiate anything concrete... by doing so you'd be coupling strictly 2 classes, which is not good. Instead DI is the right way to go, that way your Tokenizer will be able to work with no matter which type of TextProcessor (or subclasses) you fed it with.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of dependency injection as something you need special support for. It's just a technique where you move logic from inside a function to outside that function. That is, instead of

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f):
        b = B(c, d, e, f)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, c, d, e, f):
        c = C(f)

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        pass

a = A(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

you write

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, bobj):
        b = bobj

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, c, d, e, cobj):
        c = cobj

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        pass

a = A(1, 2, B(3, 4, 5, C(6)))
```

This provides better separation, as (for example) `A` no longer needs to know how to create an instance of `B` (or, for that matter, that it even *gets* an instance of `B`).